# Ajax response blank in safari but works in chrome/firefox

Tags: jquery

When I console log the response I see results in firefox and chrome but when I go to safari it is blank. I am not sure what the problem is, I tried to see if it was cached but that does not seem to the problem.

Any suggestions?

```
$('a[data-toggle="list"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    var type = $(this).parent().attr('data-type');
    $('.product-summary .' + type).text(e.target.innerText);

    var params = {
        data_type: $('.product-cw').data('product-type'),
        processor: $('.product-summary .processors').text(),
        storage: $('.product-summary .storage').text(),
        memory: $('.product-summary .memory').text(),
        graphics: $('.product-summary .graphics').text(),
        colors: $('.product-summary .color').text(),
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/product-retrieve.php',
        data: params,
        dataType: 'text',
        timeout: 30000,
        success: function (return_data) {
            var decoded_data = JSON.parse(return_data);
            $.each(decoded_data.results, function (key, val) {
                $(".price-wrap .price").text('$' + parseFloat(val.ss_price, 10).toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, "$1,").toString());
                $('#item_id').val(val.product_id);
                $('#collapseOne .panel-body').text(val.ss_productdescription);
                $('#collapseTwo .panel-body').text(val.ss_productfield15);
                $('#collapseThree .panel-body').text(val.ss_productfield17);
                $('#collapseFour .panel-body').text(val.ss_productfield13);
                if(Number(val.hollywood) !== 0) {
                    $('.store-container[data-location="Hollywood"] .stock-status').text('Quantity: ' + val.hollywood + ' Available');
                }else{
                    $('.store-container[data-location="Hollywood"] .stock-status').text('Unavailable');
                }
                if(Number(val.burbank) !== 0) {
                    $('.store-container[data-location="Burbank"] .stock-status').text('Quantity: ' + val.burbank + ' Available');
                }else{
                    $('.store-container[data-location="Burbank"] .stock-status').text('Unavailable');
                }

            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I am not sure, but isn’t that kind of crossscripting which should be denied by a browser on default settings?

Comment: I dont believe so.

Comment: So the content you're calling is on the same domain as the requesting code?

Comment: Yes it is on the same domain, which is why i am so puzzled as to why its not working right

Comment: What's the response code? Have you looked in the network console, perhaps looking at the raw dump of the response? What happens if you right click the response and open it in its own tab (at least you can do this in Firefox - I'm assuming you can in Safari but not sure.)

Comment: The response code is 200, so its definitely going through but even the raw data isnt showing.

Comment: Give a try and add `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');` on top of **php** file, maybe the problem is CORS?

Comment: So If the requested url is on the same server, why don’t you use a relativ path instead of a https url?